# Gatsby video plugin issue

Tags: gatsby, gatsby-plugin

I am new to Gatsby and I was looking into the Gatsby Video plugin, so I followed the instructions in their [docs](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/packages/gatsby-video/).

The video clip itself is named beach2.mp4 and is located in the images folder in the root of src. That location is added in my gatsby-config.js, and this a part of that file:

```
{
      resolve: `gatsby-source-filesystem`,
      options: {
        name: `images`,
        path: `${__dirname}/src/images/`,
      },
```

I installed the package itself, and added it also to my gatsby-config.js file like the following:

```
module.exports = {
  siteMetadata: {
    title: "Gatsby Default Starter",
  },
  plugins: [
    `gatsby-plugin-react-helmet`,
    `gatsby-plugin-styled-components`,
    `gatsby-transformer-sharp`,
    `gatsby-plugin-sharp`,
    `gatsby-transformer-ffmpeg`,
  ],
}
```

I followed their example query for a page query and I started to see a issue when I ran this query in GraphQL:

```
query MyQuery {
  file(relativePath: {eq: "src/images/beach2.mp4"}) {
    childVideoFfmpeg {
      webm: transcode(outputOptions: ["-crf 20", "-b:v 0"], maxWidth: 900, maxHeight: 480, fileExtension: "webm", codec: "libvpx-vp9") {
        width
        src
        presentationMaxWidth
        presentationMaxHeight
        originalName
        height
        fileExtension
        aspectRatio
      }
      mp4: transcode(maxWidth: 900, maxHeight: 480, fileExtension: "mp4", codec: "libx264") {
        width
        src
        presentationMaxWidth
        presentationMaxHeight
        originalName
        height
        fileExtension
        aspectRatio
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I got the following reply:

```
{
  "data": {
    "file": null
  }
}
```

Inside my components folder, I have a file called HeroImage.js where I have the query setup and the Video component like this:

```
import React from "react"
import { Video } from "gatsby-video"
import { graphql } from "gatsby"
import { HeroWrapper } from "../elements"

export const pageQuery = graphql`
  {
    file(relativePath: { eq: "src/images/beach2.mp4" }) {
      childVideoFfmpeg {
        webm: transcode(
          outputOptions: ["-crf 20", "-b:v 0"]
          maxWidth: 900
          maxHeight: 480
          fileExtension: "webm"
          codec: "libvpx-vp9"
        ) {
          width
          src
          presentationMaxWidth
          presentationMaxHeight
          originalName
          height
          fileExtension
          aspectRatio
        }
        mp4: transcode(
          maxWidth: 900
          maxHeight: 480
          fileExtension: "mp4"
          codec: "libx264"
        ) {
          width
          src
          presentationMaxWidth
          presentationMaxHeight
          originalName
          height
          fileExtension
          aspectRatio
        }
      }
    }
  }
`

export const MainPageVideo = props => {
  const videos = props.data.file.childVideoFfmpeg
  return (
    <HeroWrapper>
      <Video
        // poster={poster_image}
        autoPlay
        muted
        loop
        sources={[videos.webm, videos.mp4]}
      />
    </HeroWrapper>
  )
}
```

And finally, in the pages folder, in the index.js file I have done the following:

```
import React from "react"
import { Container } from "../components"
import * as styles from "../elements"
import Link from "gatsby-link"

export const IndexPage = () => {
  return (
    <Container>
      <styles.HeroWrapper>
        <styles.Video />        
      </styles.HeroWrapper>
    </Container>
  )
}

export default IndexPage
```

What have I missed out here? The video clip is not showing up.

Comment: Also struggling with this did you resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

Your `relativePath` must be relative:

```
 file(relativePath: {eq: "src/images/beach2.mp4"})
```

Should become:

```
 file(relativePath: {eq: "images/beach2.mp4"})
```

Since you have added an `image` name to your filesystem. You can query using `sourceInstanceName` like:

```
query MyQuery {
  file(sourceInstanceName: {eq: "images"}){
    childVideoFfmpeg {
      webm: transcode(outputOptions: ["-crf 20", "-b:v 0"], maxWidth: 900, maxHeight: 480, fileExtension: "webm", codec: "libvpx-vp9") {
        width
        src
        presentationMaxWidth
        presentationMaxHeight
        originalName
        height
        fileExtension
        aspectRatio
      }
      mp4: transcode(maxWidth: 900, maxHeight: 480, fileExtension: "mp4", codec: "libx264") {
        width
        src
        presentationMaxWidth
        presentationMaxHeight
        originalName
        height
        fileExtension
        aspectRatio
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The filtered query above, in your case, it will have all images plus your video (since they are in the same folder). You can make another filesystem instance to place your video there and retrieve it using the same approach, with a `sourceInstanceName` called `video`.

The rest of the code, besides a few optimizations (destructuring, etc) looks perfect.

Comment: I changed the path as you suggested, this still results in null, and I don't quite understand how to append the file(sourceInstanceName: {eq: "images"}) in the same query as above.

Comment: You don't have to append it, just replace the `filter` for the `sourceInstanceName`.

Comment: I pasted in your code,the editor complaions on one unnecessary trailing curly brace , but I guess there was supposed to be a starting curly brace after file(sourceInstanceName: {eq: "images"}), 
but I am getting {
  "data": {
    "file": {
      "childVideoFfmpeg": null
    }
  }
}